# How to give outer glow effect to column in HTML/CSS?

Tags: html, css

I am creating a website, and I want to create this effect of giving an outer glow shadow to the main column in the page ..

This page serves as an example: http://royalwatches.pk/

Note that the main column has a shadow effect on both left and right sides, to make the column appear to be 'in front' of the background.

This picture also show's what I'm talking about:

[image]

This is the page where I want to replicate this effect: http://blu-rays.pk/index.php

Can someone guide me on what CSS/HTML changes need to be done ?

Sidenote: Putting this all in jsfiddle seemed impractical, which is why I've mentioned the sites instead ..

Comment: On that site they've used a background image, but a modern solution would be to use the CSS3 `box-shadow` property, and if you want to change the colour or opacity, you can just change the values in the CSS, rather than editing an image etc.

Comment: This question is too broad. Please update your question with a specific programming question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [box-shadow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-shadow) property.

**CSS**

```
img{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px gray;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7xWe3/)

Or in your case:

```
#wrapper{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px gray;
}
```

*Note*: remove the `background-image` from `#wrapper`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember to add code so that the shadow is visible in more browsers, like so:

```
#wrapper { 
-moz-box-shadow:    0px 0px 5px gray;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px gray;
box-shadow:         0px 0px 5px gray;
}
```

More can be read about this at: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-box-shadow/